# TypeScript: How to initilize keyof T (generic) at runtime

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, strong-typing

so I have this TypeScript class where I have a generic and a property of type keyof generic, like this:

```
export class ColumnDefinition<T> {
    field: keyof T
}
```

**Compiler complains because it needs a default value which I don't have at compile time, but I don't want to allow the user to use null or undefined in this property**, so I can't do it like:

```
export class ColumnDefinition<T> {
    // can't do this, I need to make the field mandatory
    field: keyof T | undefined;
}
```

my question is, is there a way to somehow initialize the field with a default value at runtime without knowing the generic at compile time? like set whatever first key is in the generic class?

Note: I don't want to disable the ts-ignore, I'm looking for a real solution

Comment: can you include more details? Maybe the usage. I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: A guess are you trying to avoid [the error that `field` is not defined](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2ICuBbAdgEQKYDMCWaeALnvGgDwAq0WAHkVmgCYwDeAvgHzSsBQ0A6PiwgmALmgBrLAE94OaJV7teQA)? Because if so, all you should need to do is to ensure it's defined. Or use `!` if it won't be in the constructor but will most definitely be when used.

Comment: @wonderflame sure, I added a clarification in bold, -kindly tell me if it's still unclear, thanks

Comment: @VLAZ I want to give it a default value but I can't because I can't know what is generic class that will be used (the value of the field is a name of a property inside the generic class)

Comment: @HeilaAl-Mogren then how would you know that the default value would be correct? Why not require the consumer supply the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `field` with a visibility modifier (`public`, `private`, `protected`) in the constructor then it becomes a class property which is set when you pass in a value when the class is created

```ts
export class ColumnDefinition<T> {
    constructor(private field: keyof T){ }

    logField(){
        console.log(this.field);
    }
}

const colDef = new ColumnDefinition<{ x: number; }>('x');

colDef.logField(); //"x"

const badColDef = new ColumnDefinition<{ x: number; }>('foo'); //Error!
```

See it in action on [the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4GEJIK4C2AdgCLABmAlkZTJREQDwAqAfHAN4CwAUHP4gZoYUPAhjQAFGCiUAbihjA4VYEgAmALjgBrYAE8I5OMwCUHOAF9evAXCQQA5gDFKa9ZPO27AhENzAAHQOjpIwABaUaIGqGqYA3N781jwpvH5EwoJIZMYAvHBEwADu2LiEpBTUtPRMFiDaRIQARsBQ8VaskgDkIN0JNjx+ORTBTq7unh0A9NMARCBzQA)

Comment: Worth noting - declaring the property in the constructor is just a shorthand. It's not strictly required to be there for this to work, `constructor(field: keyof T) { this.field = field; } }` is also valid, as it's exactly equivalent to the shorthand: [see the compiled JS code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=5&pln=9&pc=2#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2ICuBbAdgEQKYDMCWaeALnvGgIwA8AKgHzQDeAUNK9MGREQE5LBHxuACgAO3PADcwRLNHxYQAEwBc0ANZYAnvBzRqASkYBfJidCQYCZOmz5CJMgCYa9Zm2hjJ02fKWqN2rrUANwsbBxoXLz8gkK+KupaOnqGbu5sRAAWeBAAdPHQALxyeAqKoe4mRkA)